# Change initial background color in libgdx without glClearColor?

Tags: java, background, libgdx

is it possible to change the default background color in libgdx. i want to change the background color from black to whatever color i desire, and not clear the screen. i am using ShapeRenderer to create a rectangle that is filled. i then have that rectangle move around the screen and i want to keep the previously rendered rectangle.

using Gdx.gl.glClearColor() and Gdx.gl.glClear() obviously re-renders the background color over top the previous, clearing the previously rendered rectangle.

if i dont use the Gdx.gl.glClearColor() and Gdx.gl.glClear() the background is black and the rectangle rendering and movement is what i want, other then the fact that the default background color is black. witch is not the desired look i need.

Comment: Render Rectangle filled with your desired color and size of screen first? Render to bitmap then use clear and draw bitmap?

Comment: Wrap your `Gdx.gl.glClear()` call in an appropriate if statement.

Comment: i may be thinking differently then you Tenfour04 can you elaborate. as if i use an "if" statement to constrain when and how Gdx.gl.glClear() is called. if i wanted a white background Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1) and have the Gdx.gl.glClear() being constrained by the if statement i will not having any effect from the  Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1).

Comment: Oh, I completely misunderstood your question, sorry.

Comment: I think there might be some misunderstanding of what you want. If I understand you correctly you just want to set the color of the screen and then draw rectangles every render cycle without clearing the screen. That doesn't mean on the first render cycle you can't, and I think you should, clear the screen with whatever color you want. Then as Tenfour04 suggests just use an if statement to check if it's your first render cycle, if not, don't clear the screen (this will still leave your background color until you draw over it). If we still haven't helped, please give more details.

Answer (score 0):

The frame buffer has no concept of what is background and not. If you are working exclusively with the screen's frame buffer, the only way to change the color is to clear the screen and redraw everything. So in your case you would need to store the steps you used to render everything the first time and replay those steps after clearing the screen.

What might be easier would be to use a separate frame buffer for all the content of your scene, and draw that over the background. This would require a frame buffer with an alpha component, and you would need to use `blendFuncSeparate` when rendering so alpha is preserved in this frame buffer so it can be drawn over the background. You would use a transparent clear color within the frame buffer, and whatever color you want on the main frame buffer.

libGDX FrameBuffers are a big topic and too much to explain here. You should start with the documentation, and if you start implementing it and have issues you can create a new question.

Comment: yea totally your first paragraph is what i was thinking i would need to do but that seemed like a lot of processing to store the previous state and redraw it every time.im not familiar with creating a separate buffer and using the blendFuncSeparate but what you are explaining seems to be a much more efficient way. in layman basically we are layering the different renders. Thanks this is great just needed someone to show me the door.

Comment: The difference in efficiency between the two ways depends on what your scene is. If you have a very long history of events that contribute to the final look of the scene, then maybe the second way is better. Keep in mind, the vast majority of games redraw absolutely everything on every frame so it can be animated, so in most cases it is fine to redraw everything. Also, I forgot to mention, there is a potential issue of OpenGL context loss making you lose the contents of your frame buffer (either the one on the screen or the secondary one you create if you use the second technique above).

Comment: The OpenGL context can potentially be lost on Android if the game is put in the background and then comes back. LibGDX automatically reloads all textures (that originated from image files), shaders, and meshes when this happens, but it doesn't automatically reload frame buffer contents, since it doesn't have any way to retrieve the data. If replaying the drawing of your whole scene is not doable, you would need to maybe copy the frame buffer contents to a Pixmap in `pause()` and restore them to the FrameBuffer in `resume()`.

Comment: I haven't done this myself so not 100% sure `pause` happens before potential context loss.